# nested while loop comparing two files, outside loop stops after one iteration, need to compare every line of files

Tags: perl, loops

Firstly I apologise if my formatting here is incorrect, I am very new to writing scripts (3 days) and this is my first post on this site.

I have two files which are tab separated, `File a` contains 14 columns, and `File b` contains 8 columns.

One column in `File b` has a numeric value which correlates to a range of numbers generated by two numeric fields from `File a`.
For every line in `File a`, I need to, search through the `File b` and print a combination of data from fields on both files. There will be multiple matches for each line of `File a` due to a numeric range being accepted.

The code that I have created does exactly what I want it to do but only for the first line of `File a`, and doesn't continue the loop. I have looked all over the internet and I believe it may be something to do with the fact that both files read from standard input. I have tried to correct this problem but I can't seem to get anything to work

My current understanding is that by changing one file to read from a different file descriptor my loop may work... with something such as `>$3` but I don't really understand this very well despite my research. Or possibly using the `grep` function which I am also struggling with.

Here is the outline of the code I am using now:

```
use strict;  
use warnings;

print "which file read from?\n";
my $filea = <STDIN>;  
chomp $filea;  
{
  unless (open ( FILEA, $filea) {
      print "cannot open, do you want to try again? y/n?\n?";  
      my $attempt = <STDIN>;  
      chomp $again;  
      if ($again =~ 'n') {
          exit;  
      } else {
          print "\n";   
          $filea = <STDIN>;  
          chomp $filea;  
          redo;  
      }
   }
}

#I also open fileb the same way, but wont write it all out to save space and your time.

my output = 'output.txt';  
open (OUTPUT, ">>$output");    

while (my $loop1 = <FILEA>) {  
    chomp $loop1;
    ( my $var1, my $var2, my $var3, my $var4, my $var5, my $var6, 
      my $var7, my $var8, my $var9, my $var10, my $var11, my $var12, 
      my $var13, my $var14 ) = split ( "\t", $loop1);

  #create the range of number which needs to be matched from file b.
  my $length = length ($var4);  
  my $range = ($var2 + $length);

  #perform the search loop through fileb
  while (my $loop2 = <FILEB>) {
      chomp $loop2;
    ( my $vala, my $valb, my $valc, my $vald, my $vale, my $valf, 
      my $valg) = split ( "\t", $loop2 );

    #there are then several functions and additions of the data, which all work basicly so I'll just use a quick example.

    if ($vald >= $val3 $$ $vald <= $range) {
        print OUTPUT "$val1, $vald, $val11, $valf, $vala, $val5 \n";
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this all makes sense, I tried to make everything as clear as possible, if anyone could help me edit the code so that the loop continues through all of filea that would be great.

If possible please explain what you've done. Ideally I'd like it if its possible to obtain this result without changing the code too much.

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Are the `<FILEB>` etc actually in backticks, or is that just an artifact from formatting (If so, please edit your question to remove them)? Do you already know other programming languages? From what resources are you learning (which tutorials etc.)? Anyway, your crucial mistake is actually quite common: you have already exhausted the `FILEB` handle when you come to the 2nd line of `FILEA`. So we either need to reset the file handle to the beginning, or re-open the file inside the loop, or read the whole file into memory. Someone else can write that answer.

Comment: Tip: `(my $x, my $y, my $z)` can be written as `my ($x, $y, $z)`.

Comment: Tip: `my ($var1, $var2, $var3, ... $varn)` better written as `my @var` and then referred to as `$var[0], $var[1], ... $var[$n]`.

Comment: Thr backticks were just formatting artifacts, I edited the question to remove them. I don't know any programming languages at all, I decided to attempt programming for the first time fy my degree final. I have been learning from several books such as beginning perl for bioinformatics, and google searching problems as they arise. thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Avoid naked handles when possible; use $fh (filehandle) instead of FH
2. You can use until instead of unless, and skip the redo:

   ```
   print "Enter the file name\n";
   my $file_a = <STDIN>;
   chomp $file_a;
   my $fh_a;
   until(open $fh_a, '<', $file_a) {
       print "Re-enter the file name or 'n' to cancel\n";
       $file_a = <STDIN>;
       chomp $file_a;
       if($file_a eq 'n') {
           exit;
       }
   }
   ```
3. You can (should) use an array instead of all those individual column variables: `my @cols_a = split /\t/, $line;`
4. You should read file B into an array, once, and then search that array each time you need to: `my @file_b = <$fh_b>;`
5. The result will look something like this:

   ```
   #Assume we have opened both files already . . .
   my @file_b = <$fh_b>;
   chomp @file_b;
   while(my $line = <$fh_a>) {
       chomp $line;
       my @cols_a = split /\t/, $line;
       #Remember, most arrays (perl included) are zero-indexed,
       #so $cols_a[1] is actually the SECOND column.
       my $range = ($cols_a[1] + length $cols_a[3]);

       foreach my $line_b (@file_b) {
           #This loop will run once for every single line of file A.
           #Not efficient, but it will work.
           #There are, of course, lots of optimisations you can make
           #(starting with, for example, storing file B as an array of array
           #references so you don't have to split each line every time)
           my @cols_b = split /\t/, $line_b;
           if($cols_b[3] > $cols_a[2] && $cols_b[3] < ($cols_a[2] + $range)) {
               #Do whatever here
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, I have managed to get everything working now which is fantastic! I also understand a bit better the whole issue I was causing, this was exactly what I needed. I know the code will need optimising and I may tackle this more once I become a little more proficient.